# how can I fill null value with S.T in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone know how to fill null value in PostgreSQL?
For example, Null values are replaced with X

```
column
A
B
Null
C
D
Null
```

should be:

```
column
A
B
x
C
D
x
```

Comment: What is "S.T"? What is the code you are using, what happens, and how is what happens different from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to return a different value if a column is `null`

```
select coalesce(the_column, 'x') as the_column
from the_table;
```